Oracle APEX - Export to excel - top alignment
I'm currently working with Oracle APEX version 23.2.5 and I'm looking to customize the way data is exported to Excel. Specifically, I need to set the cell alignment to "top" globally for all the cells in my exported Excel files.
In the IG attributes, I see that there are settings for aligning text to the left, right, or center. However, I couldn't find an option to align the text to the top within the cells.
Is there a way to achieve this alignment setting? Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that can be applied globally to all cells upon export. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

It is easy to vertically align cells' contents with Apex, but - it doesn't affect download to Excel. Whatever I tried, I failed. Then I asked ChatGPT which suggest we use PL/SQL (download to BLOB, convert to CLOB, fix the "alignment" tag, insert contents into a table, provide download link). I didn't try it, but you can. Instructions (so that you wouldn't have to ask it yourself): https://chatgpt.com/c/1c89902e-a8fe-4d5d-ba55-7e9bda3fda16
